# How to generate parent child column in Talend

Tags: arrays, talend

How to create data tree structure in `Talend` using `xml` file.
I am trying using `tWriteJsonfield` component.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write into a XML structure, you should try the tXMMap component,

[See talend documentation](https://help.talend.com//pages/viewpage.action?pageId=260019804)

You can also import an existing XML structure from a file through the Metadata section.

[How to create Input and Output Xml File Metadata](https://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?idTuto=10)